# Operands in javascript calculator won't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a simple calculator with the ability to choose the operand between +,-,/,*, but the program is doing random operations, sometimes adding when it should be multiply etc.

This is the javascript:

```js
submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit1')

num1 = document.querySelector('#number1')
num2 = document.querySelector('#number2')
solution = document.querySelector('.solution')

operator = document.querySelector('#operator')

let opSelection = operator.options[operator.selectedIndex].value

function math(a, b) {
  // a = parseInt(num1.value);
  // b = parseInt(num2.value);

  if (opSelection == '-') {
    return a - b;

  } else if (opSelection == '+') {
    return a + b;

  } else if (opSelection == '*') {
    return a * b;

  } else {
    return a / b;
  }

}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  solution.innerHTML = math(parseInt(num1.value), parseInt(num2.value))

})
```

```html
<div class="quiz__form">
  <div class="quiz">What is
    <input id="number1" type="number">
    <select id="operator">
      <option id="plus" value="">+</option>
      <option id="minus" value="">-</option>
      <option id="multiply" value="">*</option>
      <option id="divide" value="">/</option>
    </select>
    <input id="number2" type="number"> =
    <p class="solution"></p>
  </div>


</div>
<button class="submit1" type=submit>Submit</button>
```

I'm sure it's simple, but I'm new and self-teaching, so any help you might have would be so appreciated!

Comment: You have set explicit `value=""` attributes.

Comment: A general piece of advice which would have made diagnosis easier - you can open the dev tools in your browser and add a breakpoint to the first line in your function, then you can see what's happening as the code runs, line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the comment said, you need to set the "value" attribute.

```html
<option id="plus" value="+">+</option>
<option id="minus" value="-">-</option>
<option id="multiply" value="*">*</option>
<option id="divide" value="/">/</option>
```

Also, I found one more bug where the operator is only being assigned at the start of the page. You need to update the `opSelection` variable every time the user clicks submit, and not just at the beginning.

An example way to fix this is to change the line `let opSelection = operator.options[operator.selectedIndex].value` to simply `let opSelection` and then add the following line `opSelection = operator.options[operator.selectedIndex].value` directly before the `solution.innerHTML...` line.